# Primary decomposition in a Dedekind Domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

I was a little bit puzzled with the following problem that I have recently come across:

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and let $P$ be a prime ideal in $R$. Is it true that $P^k$ is an irreducible ideal? (Here, an *irreducible* ideal $I$ means that if $I=J \cap K$ for some ideals $J$ and $K$, then either $I=J$ or $I=K$.)

Here is how I have progressed:
We know that in a *Dedekind domain*, ideals can be factored uniquely into product of prime ideals. So, here if $P^k$ is not irreducible then $P^k=I\cap J$ for some ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ such that $I\supset P^k$ and $J\supset P^k$, where the inclusions are proper. Now, we factorize the ideals $I$ and $J$ into product of prime ideals viz.  $I=\wp_{\alpha_1}^{\beta_1}\cdots\wp_{\alpha_k}^{\beta_k}$ and $J=\wp_{\gamma_1}^{\delta_1}\cdots\wp_{\gamma_k}^{\delta_k}$. Now, in a *Dedekind domain*, contains means divides. So, $I=\wp_{\alpha_1}^{\beta_1}\cdots\wp_{\alpha_k}^{\beta_k}$ divides $P^k$ and $J=\wp_{\gamma_1}^{\delta_1}\cdots\wp_{\gamma_k}^{\delta_k}$ divides $P^k$. Now, unique factorization implies that $I=P^a$ and $J=P^b$ for some integers $a,b \leq k$. Without loss of any generality, suppose that $ a < b$. Then $I \cap J = P^b$. So, $b$ must be equal to $k$ and hence $P^k$ is irreducible.

I am not sure if I'm missing out something...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true and your argument is fine.

Note that in the integers the statement could be restated as: if $\operatorname{lcm} (m,n)=p^k$ then $m$ or $n$ is equal to $p^k$.

And, indeed also for Dedekind domains the  intersection of the ideals is their LCM in the semigroup of ideals, which has unique factorization.